# How to handle aws dynamo db 400 KB record limit without changing my codebase

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

In aws dynamo db we cannot store more than 400KB data in a single record [[Reference](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-limits/#dynamodb-item-size-limit)].
Based on suggestions online I can either compress the data before storing or upload part of it to aws s3 bucket which I am fine by

But my application (javascript/express server plus many js lambdas/microservices) is too large and adding the above logic which require a heavy re-write and extensive testing. Currently there is an immediate requirement from a big client that demands >400KB storage in db, so is there any alternative way to solve the problem that doesn't make me change my existing code to fetch the record from db.

I was thinking more in these lines:
My backend makes a dynamo db call to fetch the record as its doing now (we use a mix of vogels and aws-sdk to make db calls) -> The call is intercepted by a lambda (or something else) which handles the necessary compression/decompression/s3 with dynamodb and returns the data to the backend.

Is the above approach possible to do and if yes then how can i go about implementing it? Or if you have a better way, please do tell.

PS. Going forward I will definitely re-write my codebase to take care of this, what I am asking for is an immediate stopgap solution.

Comment: I'm curious. What kind of data is this that exceeds 400kb for a single item?

Comment: One possible workaround is to save your "large data" to an S3 bucket, then store the S3 object address in your DynamoDB record.

Comment: I initially thought the same, but would like to avoid refactoring old code everywhere and if possible have this in 1 single place without changing existing code

Answer (score 0):

Split the data into multiple items. You’ll have to change a little client code but hopefully you have a data access layer so it’s just a small change in one place. If you don’t have a DAL, from now on always have a DAL. :)

For the payload of a big item, use the regular item as the manifest which can point at the segmented items. Then batch get items those segmented items.

This assumes compression alone isn’t always sufficient. If it is, do that.

Comment: Sadly we don't have a DAL. we directly make calls to dynamodb (via vogels or aws-sdk) in different files and also microservices (lambdas). Also the codebase is in javascript with almost no tests, so only way to make sure changes in so many places didn't break anything is to manually test them.

Comment: Spliting the data into multple items sounds good but given my current situation refactoring in so many places is not possible given the timeframe.
Is it possible to make a function that intercepts calls to dynamodb (like a lambda) where I can write this logic, this way it will be a lot easier to test, 
Or maybe intercept vogels/aws-sdk library api and add the item-splitting logic there?